# SharePoint Add List Item based on ContentType

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-workflow

I have created a SharePoint Workflow which will be triggered whenever a new item is created. Moreover, I added the workflow to a content type which was associated to a list.

Now I need to add a list item which will triggers the workflow. I tried the following solutions but didn't work:

```
SPListItemCollection listItems = list.Items;
SPListItem item = listItems.Add();
SPContentType ct = list.ContentTypes["Content Type Name"];
item["ContentTypeId"] = ct.Id;
item.Update();
```

Since the content type was added to the site i also tried:

```
SPContentType ct = web.ContentTypes["Content Type Name"];
```

However, none of the solutions triggered the workflow even though the ContentTypeID is being retrieved correctly. Could you please help me?

Comment: You are missing item.Update() after you created it. SharePoint only creates your item after you call Update on the item you created using list.Items.Add()

Comment: It was implemented. Question fixed

Comment: RononDex, the update statement was included in the actual code but was not included the snippet. I included the Update statement in the question so that I don't confuse other people. That means that the workflow is not being triggered when I am inserting the list item as done in the snippet

Comment: I see, sorry for the misunderstanding. So how did you create the workflow? With Sharepoint Designer?

Comment: Yes I created the workflow through the SharePoint Designer as a Sharepoint 2010 Approval Workflow.
In addition, I am running that piece of code as through the RunWithElevatedPrivileges method. I don't know if this makes a difference or not

Comment: Ah I see. As far as I know in order for approval workflows to work you need to activate a specific Site or Web feature  and enable the list in its settings to be able to check out items and to enable the approval process.

Comment: When the item is added manually the approval workflow works as a charm. The issue arises only when I create the item programatically.

Comment: Are the items you create programatically checked out when you look at them in your browser? If yes can you try to check them in after you call `item.Update` using `SPListItem.File.CheckIn();`?

Answer (score 0):

the issue was that I was running the code with ElevatedPriviledges which was not triggering the workflow.